# Show that $H=\oplus_{\alpha \in \sigma(T)}\text{ker}(\alpha I -T)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $T$ is an operator on a Hilbert space $H$ such that $\sigma(T)=\sigma_{p}(T)$ (point spectrum of $T$), and for each $\alpha \in \sigma(T)$, the corresponding eigenspace ker$(\alpha I-T)$ is a reducing subspace for $T$. We are also given that $\sigma(T)\subset \mathbb{R}.$ Then it is to be shown that $H=\oplus_{\alpha \in \sigma(T)}\text{ker}(\alpha I -T)$, that is $H$ is spanned by the orthogonal eigenspaces of $T$

First, it can be shown that for $\alpha, \beta \in \sigma(T)(=\sigma_{p}(T)), \alpha \neq \beta$, the corresponding eigen spaces ker($\alpha I-T$) and ker($\beta I-T$) are orthogonal. For this it suffices to show that if $\lambda \in \sigma_{p}(T)$, then $\bar{\lambda}=\lambda$ (since $\sigma(T)\subset \mathbb{R}$) is in $\sigma_{p}(T^{*})$. i.e. $Tx=\lambda x$ implies $T^{*}x=\lambda x$.

Suppose $Tx=\lambda x$. Then each $y\in H$ can be written as $y=y_{1}+y_{2}$ where $y_{1}\in \text{ker}(\lambda I-T)$ and $y_{2} \in \text{ker}(\lambda I-T)^{\perp}$.
Then $\langle T^{*}x,y\rangle=\langle T^{*}x,y_{1}+y_{2}\rangle=\langle x, Ty_{1}+Ty_{2}\rangle=\langle x, Ty_{1}\rangle$ for, since $T$ reduces ker($\lambda I-T$), $Ty_{2} \in \text{ker}(\lambda I-T)^{\perp}$ and $x \in \text{ker}(\lambda I-T)$.

Thus $\langle T^{*}x,y\rangle=\langle x, Ty_{1}\rangle=\langle x, \lambda y_{1}\rangle=\langle\lambda x, y_{1}\rangle=\langle\lambda x, y\rangle$.

This is true for all $y\in H$, hence $T^{*}x=\lambda x$.

This shows that eigenspaces corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal.

Next we must show that these eigenspaces span $H$. Could someone help with this?

Let $\oplus_{\alpha \in \sigma(T)}\text{ker}(\alpha I -T)=M$, say, and suppose $M^{\perp}\neq \{0\}$. Then since each $M_{\alpha}=\text{ker}(\alpha I-T)$ is a reducing subspace for $T$,  $T \restriction_{M^{\perp}}$ is a bounded operator on $M^{\perp}$. Also $\sigma(T \restriction_{M^{\perp}})\subset \sigma(T)$. Then $T \restriction_{M^{\perp}}$ has empty eigen spectrum. Does it also follow that $\sigma(T \restriction_{M^{\perp}})=\emptyset$? How?

If the above is true, then we have arrived at a contradiction, whence $M^{\perp}= \{0\}$.

If not, how else can it be shown that $H=\oplus_{\alpha \in \sigma(T)}\text{ker}(\alpha I -T)$?

Comment: What is $\sigma_{e}(T)$? Is $\oplus_{\alpha\in\sigma(T)}$ some kind of orthogonal sum? How is it defined, and why does it make sense here?

Comment: $\sigma_{e}(T)$ is the point spectrum or eigen spectrum of $T$. $\oplus _{\alpha \in \sigma(T)}$ is the orthogonal direct sum of the corresponding eigen spaces (since every spectral value is assumed to be an eigen value). It is the closure of the span of the union of the orthogonal bases of each $\text{ker}(\alpha I-T)$.

Comment: Regarding your question near the end, it does not follow that $T$ on $M^{\perp}$ is the zero operator. You need a stronger assumption for this because otherwise you could have a $T$ (let's say self-adjoint) that has point spectrum on a set and other spectrum as well.